# c# model when one property is json

Tags: c#, json, model

i have a simple data

```
      [{
            "rowNumber": 1,
            "name": "aaa",
            "results": "json string data"
        },
        {
            "rowNumber": 2,
            "name": "bbb",
            "results": "json string data"
        }],
```

then i have a class

```
    public class CeremonySaloonSaloonItems
{
    public long? saloonId { get; set; }
    public string saloonName { get; set; }
    public string results{ get; set; }
}
```

where results is another list that here is json
then and after i import data i loop all data and deserialize results.
but i think must be a better way to get data deserialized.

Comment: You can deserialize/serialize a `List<CeremonySaloonSaloonItems>`. Your class's Properties names don't match the JSON's though. If you want to change the name of a property, you can add a `[JsonProperty()]` attribute: e.g., `[JsonProperty("rowNumber")] public long? saloonId { get; set; }`. `rowNumber` deseriaizes to `saloonId` and serializes back to `rowNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

And add this **lines of code**

```
JavaScriptSerializer js            = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
CeremonySaloonSaloonItems Ceremony = js.Deserialize<CeremonySaloonSaloonItems>(jsonData);  
string name                        = Ceremony.Name;  
string description                 = Ceremony.Description;
```

use javascript Serializer and give your class as a list generic type.
Using **JSONCONVERT**:
Import newtonsoft json from nuget package manager.
And this *code.*

```
CeremonySaloonSaloonItems Ceremony = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CeremonySaloonSaloonItems>(jsondata);  

Response.Write(Ceremony.Name);
```

Using Json .Net and `Foreach`

```
var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CeremonySaloonSaloonItems>(json);
foreach (var obj in jsonObj.entity)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.name);
}
```

Comment: my data is ok, when revive in coe is ok too, name and rownumber is ok too, but just results is json, i need to deserialze results on fly not in loop

Comment: I just edited how you can use foreach with it but there is no parent array in your json .  to which you are applying the foreach. If you want to use foreach please use this format.{"objectType" : "Subscriber", "objectList":[{"firstName":"name1","email":"email@example.com","address":"exampleAddress"},{"firstName":"name2","email":"email2@example.com","address":"exampleAddress2"}]}